# Does Dell PowerEdge R710 support Win 2012 Server

Tags: dell-poweredge, windows-server-2012

Is it possible to install win 2012 server on Dell power edge R710...? 
Explain

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Why do you think it wouldn't it be supported?

The [Dell PowerEdge R710](http://www.dell.com/downloads/global/products/pedge/en/server-poweredge-r710-specs-en.pdf) system runs/rans with the Nehalem/Westmere processor lines. That's only one generation removed from the current. E.g. 2009 through 2012.

Dell outlines the firmware revisions needed to run Windows 2012 with the R710 [here](http://en.community.dell.com/techcenter/os-applications/w/wiki/3868.dell-bios-support-for-windows-server-2012.aspx). Also see the compatibility matrix [here](http://advisors.dell.com/AgileWeb/iDrivematrixView.aspx).